# File Upload to SFTP Using C++

Tags: c++

I want to write C++ Code for Upload file to SFTP from the Local Machine can any one suggest me for that?

or if any example or reference code is there then please provide me thnx.

Comment: C++ is not designed to do such things out of the box, so this is essentially asking for a tool or a library which is explicitly off topic. Even if you wanted to create a library on your own, then it would be too broad. This is complicated. Not to mention the question itself is kind of zero-effort.

Comment: @slim this question is not a duplicate, the connection & auth is very different between SFTP and FTP.

Comment: Libssh, libssh2, both do SFTP apparently.